# How would I index a query that utilizes INNER JOIN and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I'm trying to get users that `1234567` is following, ordered by their `active_at` DESC.

```
SELECT U.* FROM users U 
INNER JOIN follows F
ON F.to_user_id = U.id
WHERE F.from_user_id = 1234567
ORDER BY U.active_at DESC
```

`follows` table only has 2 columns - `from_user_id` and `to_user_id`.  These two columns foreign key to `users.id`.

Currently, I have an index on `U.active_at`.  However, my intuition is telling me that the index will never be used due to the presence of the INNER JOIN.

How exactly should I index this query?

Comment: Intuition? What's wrong with EXPLAIN?

Comment: And what's wrong with trying and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make this totally efficient.

The best thing is to have

```
F:  PRIMARY KEY(from_user_id, to_user_id)
U:  INDEX(id) -- (If `id` is the PRIMARY KEY, don't add this index.)
```

Do not have an auto-inc primary key(id) on F.

If other queries need to start with `to_user_id` have a secondary `INDEX(to_user_id, from_user_id)`.

[*Many:many mapping table tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .